# How to prevent swiftlint -fix --format to change format style of closure?

Tags: swift, format, closures, swiftlint

I have a Swift project in which is used `swiftlint` and my local `version is 0.50.03`.

My problem is with styling on closure after running `swiftlint lint --fix --format` command.

**Here is the scenario:**

I have a closure that will be formatted like this after applying `Xcode formatting rules (cmd + I)`:

```
ASStoreManager.shared.makeRegisterAPIRequest(withEmail: emailInputView.formattedText,
                                                 withPassword: passwordInputView.formattedText,
                                                 withFullName: fullNameInputView.formattedText,
                                                 completion: { errors in
        ASLoaderUtils.shared.hide()
        
        if let errors = errors {
            ASAlertUtils.shared.presentAlert(withErrors: errors)
        } else {
            ASFirebaseManager.logEvent(withEventName: ASFirebaseConstants.Events.User.signUp,
                                       withParameters: ASFirebaseManager.getUserParameters())
            
            let viewController = ASConfirmationViewController(withConfirmationViewControllerType: .Register)
            viewController.callbacks.buttonDidTap = {
                ASStoreManager.shared.makeLogIn()
            }
            
            let navigationController = viewController.embedToNavigationController()
            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
        }
    })
```

After running the `swiftlint` command will be formatted like this:

```
        ASStoreManager.shared.makeRegisterAPIRequest(withEmail: emailInputView.formattedText,
                                                 withPassword: passwordInputView.formattedText,
                                                 withFullName: fullNameInputView.formattedText,
                                                 completion: { errors in
                                                    ASLoaderUtils.shared.hide()

                                                    if let errors = errors {
                                                        ASAlertUtils.shared.presentAlert(withErrors: errors)
                                                    } else {
                                                        ASFirebaseManager.logEvent(withEventName: ASFirebaseConstants.Events.User.signUp,
                                                                                   withParameters: ASFirebaseManager.getUserParameters())

                                                        let viewController = ASConfirmationViewController(withConfirmationViewControllerType: .Register)
                                                        viewController.callbacks.buttonDidTap = {
                                                            ASStoreManager.shared.makeLogIn()
                                                        }

                                                        let navigationController = viewController.embedToNavigationController()
                                                        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

                                                        self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
                                                    }
                                                 })
```

I tried with the next `swiftlint configurations params` in both `disabled_rules & opt_in_rules` or just in `opt_in_rules` or just in `disabled_rules` but nothing is working from stopping `swiftlint` to format my closure style:

```
disabled_rules:
  - closure_body_length
  - closure_end_indentation
  - closure_parameter_position
  - closure_spacing
  - multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure
  - trailing_closure

opt_in_rules:
  - closure_body_length
  - closure_end_indentation
  - closure_parameter_position
  - closure_spacing
  - multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure
  - trailing_closure
```

**My question: How can I stop `swiftlint` from formatting my closure and keep the `Xcode format style`?**

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: As for the formatting, just start the function input argument on a new line, then they won't be indented so much and Xcode's and swiftlint's formatting will match.

Comment: Indeed, if i start with the function input argument on a new line, the Xcode's formatting will match swiftlint's formatting, but would be there any way to keep the first input argument on the same line with the function and just prevent the formatting on closure?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to achieve that. Putting the function input arguments on a new line also makes it easier to view the code on smaller screens and smaller windows, such as during code review, since it removes the need for horizontal scrolling.